# create a square div with the option to make it taller

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm using [this method](http://jsfiddle.net/josedvq/38Tnx/) to create responsive squares.
if the text fits i want the div to keep his aspect ratio of 1:1 but if the text is longer i want the div height to expand. is that possible?

```css
.square-box{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #4679BD;
}
.square-box:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
.square-content{
    position:  absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: white;
}
.square-content div {
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
.square-content span {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white
}
```

```html
<div class='square-box'>
    <div class='square-content'>
        <div>
            <span>Aspect ratio 1:1</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple div to show responsive  div in height

```css
.square {
        background: #000;
        width: 50vw;
        
    }
    .square h1 {
        color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<div class="square">
         <h1>This is a Square</h1>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using jQuery. It's running an interval that will check to see if the box size is equal to the `max-width` of the content. if it's true it will resize the box and if it's false it will change it to 50% height.

I  changed the following css properties:

```
.square-content div {
   display: table;
   height: 100%;
   max-width:500px;
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

jQuery:

```
function change () {
    if ($(".square-box").width() <= 500) {
        $(".square-box").css("height", "800px");
    } else {
        $(".square-box").css("height", "50%");
    }
}

setInterval(change, 100);
```

It's easier to understand here:
http://jsfiddle.net/v5f8hwzo/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `padding-top:100%` - use viewport units.

So if the box width is 50% of the viewport width, we can simply set the  dimensions of the box to be `width: 50vw` and `min-height: 50vw`

Setting `min-height: 50vw` ensures that when the text *doesn't fill the box* - it keeps the 1:1 square aspect ratio, but if the text *fills the box* - the box will grow according to the length of the text.

### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/38Tnx/1302/) (Resize to see the effect)

```css
.square-box {
  position: relative;
  background: #4679BD;
  width: 50vw;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.square-content {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50vw;
  min-height: 50vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  /* vertically center text */
}
.square-content span {
  color: white
}
```

```html
<div class='square-box'>
  <div class='square-content'>
    <div><span>Not much text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class='square-box'>
  <div class='square-content'>
    <div><span>Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text Lots of text </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually browser support is very good IE9+ http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units